# How can I follow the progress of miner signaling for Taproot activation during the Speedy Trial deployment?

Tags: soft-fork, taproot, activation-mechanism

How can I follow the progress of miner signaling for Taproot activation during the Speedy Trial deployment? Can I use bitcoin-cli to track the signaling progress?

This was [asked](https://bitcoinhackers.org/@pox/106096826461763333) by pox on Mastodon and has been paraphrased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hampus Sjöberg has set up a site (https://taproot.watch/) with a graphic for which blocks have signaled for Taproot activation and a breakdown by mining pools. It was announced [here](https://twitter.com/hampus_s/status/1387079347425644549?s=20) on Twitter.

AJ Towns [stated](https://mastodon.social/@ajtowns/106108519281794313) on Mastodon that once signaling starts the Bitcoin Core RPC `getblockchaininfo` will report the number of signaling blocks in the current period.

David Harding [added](https://hash.social/@harding/106107255784967851) on Mastodon:

> If you want to implement checking yourself, you can use
> the versionhex in either debug.log or the results of `getblock`.
> Taproot is using bit 2.  See the versionbits [FAQ](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/06/08/version-bits-miners-faq/) for details about
> bits:

pox also [wrote](https://bitcoinhackers.org/@pox/106107502434761944) an awk script:

```
gawk -F'[= ]' '/UpdateTip/ { print("block="$7" taproot="and($9,2)) }' <~/.bitcoin/debug.log
```

If you are interested in which mining pools have already indicated that they will be signaling readiness for Taproot activation see [taprootactivation.com](https://taprootactivation.com/).

Update on June 14th 2021: Taproot activation has now locked in and Taproot rules should now be enforced in November 2021. To verify this on your node use this script provided by emzy on IRC:

```
bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo | jq '.softforks | .taproot
```

which should result in:

```
"status": "locked_in"
```